# Unable to fetch from mirror

Tags: git, version-control, mirror

I am in the process of migrating a git repository from Github to a local Atlassian Stash server. While I'm working out infrastructure, developers are still working against Github, and my intention was to mirror their work from Github to Stash until I go live with Stash.

Anyways, I set up my local mirror as follows:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git myrepo-mirror
cd myrepo-mirror
git remote set-url --push origin nowhere.com # prevent accidental pushes to origin
git remote add stash https://stash/myproj/myrepo.git # set "stash" remote for pushing
```

Then I would periodically (via cron) fetch and push:

```
git fetch -p origin
git push --mirror stash
```

However, it fails at the `git fetch`. I get the following error:

> fatal: refs/remotes/origin/master tracks both refs/heads/master and
>   refs/remotes/origin/master 
>   Unexpected end of command stream

I run `git branch -r` and it looks normal. So I run `git ls-remote origin` and I see the usual, with these two strange (I think) guys at the bottom:

```
 7e438ee97be8c7cbd8012c3c96b60e3ff8cb3c2c       refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
 7e438ee97be8c7cbd8012c3c96b60e3ff8cb3c2c       refs/remotes/origin/master
```

I figure the last one is the problem, but I'm not sure, or how to fix it. I also ran `git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch` and see:

```
+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
+refs/*:refs/*
```

but again, I'm not sure if or how to fix.

#### Full disclosure

I made an earlier attempt to mirror that seemed to be working fine, but I accidentally `git push --mirror` while testing which essentially force pushed origin with an out of date working copy (Yeah, I know). I attempted to rebuild by going to my CI server that had fetched recently  and recreating all the branches, then mirror pushing back to github to get everything back to normal. That may be where these wierd ref problems started.

#### Aside

I also tried `git clone --bare url` and then doing my `git fetch -p origin && git push --mirror stash` and it says it's working, but I never see the updated commits on my Stash repo.

Comment: Have you looked in `.git/config`? Maybe you can change something there and see the error? If not, you can also look at `.git/refs/*`. Be careful when you delete something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  I'm curious, if you repeat this step:

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git myrepo-mirror
```

with a new fresh copy, and immediately after it finishes, `cd` into the new clone and repeat this as well:

```
git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
```

will you get the same three refspec lines?  If so, there's something wrong with `git clone --mirror`.  If not, something else messed this up.

Now, on to the problem itself.  The problem lies in these three `fetch` lines:

```
+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
+refs/*:refs/*
```

The first one tells `git fetch` that after fetching from `origin`, if "they" (the remote) had branch `refs/pull/master/head`, for instance, your git should rename that to `refs/remotes/origin/pr/master`.  The `+` means "force", i.e., even if you already have a `refs/remotes/origin/pr/master`, replace it with the new `refs/pull/master/head` SHA-1.

The second one tells `git fetch` that after fetching from `origin`, if they had `refs/heads/master`, for instance, your git should rename that to `refs/remotes/origin/master` (this is the normal, non-`--mirror` setting).  As before, "force" is set; your `refs/remotes/origin/master` will be overwritten with the new SHA-1.

The third one tells `git fetch` that after fetching from `origin`, if they had `refs/heads/master`, your git should overwrite your own `refs/heads/master` with the new SHA-1; if they had `refs/pull/master/head`, your git should overwrite your own `refs/pull/master/head`.

So, you run `git fetch`, and it turns out that gosh, they *do* have a `refs/heads/master`.  (What a surprise ... not!)  So your git is supposed to:

- rename it to `refs/remotes/origin/master`,
- no, wait, rename it to `refs/heads/master`!

This is where your `fetch` stops with an error: it must pick just one of these two, and like the proverbial donkey halfway between two haystacks, it simply freezes up and dies instead.<sup>1</sup>

(Had there been a `refs/pull/master/head`, your git would have been told to rename that to both `refs/remotes/origin/pr/master` and also `refs/pull/master/head`.  This, too, would fail.  But the `refs/heads/master` failure sufficed to stop things.)

The fix lies in deciding whether you want a true mirror.  If so, delete all but the `+refs/*:refs/*` line.  Your git will then, on `git fetch` or `git remote update`, turn all their `refs/*` references into your own references with exactly the same name.  (And add `--prune` to have your git discard references on your side that no longer exist on theirs.  That's what you've been doing, so I imagine you really do want a true mirror.)

(Note that all this is specific to remote `origin`.  If/when you run `git push --mirror stash` to do a mirror-style push to a remote named `stash`, that's quite independent of the `fetch` configuration for the remote named `origin`.  With `--mirror` you're essentially setting the `push` refspec to `+refs/*:refs/*` with automatic pruning, so this is much like having that remote fetch from you, with that remote's configuration set up as a fetch mirror.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you try this with a real donkey, he'll just eat both haystacks.  Which just goes to show that git is not really a smart ... well, you know. :-)

Comment: This makes more sense. Just prior to your answer, I changed the fetch via `git config remote.origin.fetch 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'` thereby ignoring the `/refs/remotes/*` and it started working. I'm not sure if that's the best `fetch` config, but at least it's working.

And yeah, when I run `git config --get-all` directly after cloning the mirror, I get the same three lines. I'll try on some different repositories and see what I get.

Comment: With `+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` you'll get a partial mirror, in that your git will bring over all branches (branches are refs under `refs/heads/`) but nothing else, e.g., no tags (`refs/tags/*`).